# Facebook Like Box doesn't work

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I am trying to use the fb like box, in the generators preview everything works fine. After pasting the generated code in my website and hitting the "like"-button, a pop-up appears, connects to facebook and closes itself again. But nothing happens, i have not liked the facebook page.

Here is the code:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "http://connect.facebook.net/de_DE/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-like-box" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Verband-Nordrhein-Westf%C3%A4lischer-Omnibusunternehmen-eV/494051873994513" data-width="292" data-height="300" data-show-faces="false" data-stream="false" data-header="true"></div>
```

Comment: do you have any error on your console when you debug with firebug or chrome developer tools?

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the script after the first  tag of your page.

Put the `<div class="fb-like-box" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Verband-Nordrhein-Westf%C3%A4lischer-Omnibusunternehmen-eV/494051873994513" data-width="292" data-height="300" data-show-faces="false" data-stream="false" data-header="true"></div>`
where you want to be shown in your page.

Not exactly after the script.